# Is the error I noticed a harmless typo?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, reference-request, prime-numbers

Here

http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf

, at page $2$ at the bottom, it is stated that the number of primes not exceeding $x$, denoted by $\pi(x)$, satisfies the double-inequality

$$\frac{x}{\ln(x)}(1 + \frac{1}{\ln(x)} + \frac{2}{\ln^2(x)})\le \pi(x) \le \frac{x}{\ln(x)}(1 + \frac{1}{\ln(x)} + \frac{2.334}{\ln^2(x)})$$ for $x \ge 2\ 953\ 652\ 287$

However, the right inequality is false for $x = 2\ 953\ 652\ 287$, but seems to be true for $x>2\ 953\ 652\ 287$

> Is this a harmless typo or is the constant $2.334$ in the bounds wrong ?
>
> Can anyone approve that the above double inequality actually holds for $x > 2\ 953\ 652\ 287$ ?

Comment: Where exactly? Do not only provide a link to a 20 page pdf. Indeed, you should give a complete reference and not link the pdf but rather the abstract site http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442.

Comment: @quid: See equation 6.7 of the paper.

Comment: Thanks. With the crude tools I have around atm (W|A) it seems I can confirm it is off by 1 (or 0.6 something to be more precise). Is this what you get too? What did you use?  Given the way the proof is written I suppose the issue is just there; the verification for the small values. But hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @quid Yes, the error is very small and probably it is only a harmless typo. But you will admit that such errors (even if they are harmless) lead to some doubts whether the claim is reliable. Therefore my question.

Comment: Yes, sure. Eventually you might consider contacting the author.

Comment: @quid A similar problem : I found the claim that $|\pi(x)-li(x)|<\frac{\sqrt{x}log(x)}{8\pi}$ for $x\ge 2657$ assuming the Riemann hypothesis is true. I checked it numerically, and it seems with $Li(x)$ instead of $li(x)$ , the inequality is also satisfied. Additionally, the claim also holds for smaller values. Maybe, there is a special reason lying in the method of the proof, that $1)$ "li(x)" is used and $2)$ that the bound $2657$ is used. Unfortunately, it is very difficult to verify such results.

Comment: I just came across this looking for as yet unanswered questions I could answer. I don't know the answer to your question (but like quid I expect it's just a mistake in the check for small $x$). But with respect to your last comment: if you haven't yet seen it, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556334/riemann-hypothesis-and-the-logarithmic-integral) should be interesting to you.